# Are players who are turned into monsters by the traitor affected negatively by the house?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

This question is predominately about Betrayal at the House on the Hill Haunt #27. Spoilers below:

> The other night I was playing Haunt 27, and I was too close to the blob at one point and was turned into a blob person (a specific monster determined by the haunt who gets its own speed stat and some limitations, but otherwise operates under the player's discretion).
>
> At one point another player pulled the event card that required all players in certain rooms/near windows to roll a sanity check (I BELIEVE it was a sanity check, at least) to not be tempted by the howling wind and immediately move to the patio. I was one of the players that would be affected, and we were unsure as to whether or not my blob-person status would exempt me from having to roll.
>
> Because the traitor book said my speed was now 2, does that mean I disregard my character card and ONLY have a speed stat and therefore don't have a sanity stat and wouldn't be able to roll in the first place? But as a follow-up, does becoming a blob-person (or any other player-turned-monster) now align you on the traitor's side so that the house doesn't affect you negatively in the first place? (Such as being able to avoid taking damage for falling through the collapsed room, etc.) We were split on this but I feel like the intention of the game is that you're now working for the traitor's side and the house will help you accomplish your goal without hindering your progress.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Either interpretation is valid.

I remember playing this same scenario, but don't remember that question coming up at all. I reread through both the hero and traitor books for this scenario, and this seems to be a gap between the literal as-written rules and the general intent/theme of the game.

As written, a blob-person still would count as a hero and a regular character, and would be affected by the house and other things that affect all players. They would still have their normal stats except for their speed which is changed. This is based on the fact that the rules specify what is different about blob people, and those changes do not include giving them traitor or monster status:

> A Blobperson can't attack, be attacked, draw cards, use the Mystic Elevator, or discover rooms.

That being said, given that the rules are known to be full of holes, it's reasonable to believe that the blob people are intended to be treated as monsters, except that they are controlled by each player, instead of by the traitor. This is based on the fact that their stat is listed in the rules the same way all monsters' stats are, and the fact that their goal is to help the traitor win, exactly like the goal of the traitor and other monsters.